# Can I install an external plugin using the PhoneGap or Codova CLI on a project created in PhoneGap Desktop?

Tags: admob, phonegap-plugins, cordova-plugins, phonegap-cli, phonegap-desktop-app

I created an App using PhoneGap Desktop. I now want to add an AdMob plugin. I understand PhoneGap Desktop only has core plugins.  Can you create with PhoneGap Desktop and then modify with a CLI interface/ install an external plugin? If so, what CLI is best for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do this with the phonegap cli. To install:

```
npm install -g phonegap
```

Then navigate on the command line to the directory containing your PhoneGap app. It shouldn't matter if it was created with the desktop app or the phonegap cli. Then:

```
phonegap plugin add cordova-admob
```